# Freezing an unbaked pie

Tags: freezing, pie

I combined sugar and flour and mixed with frozen blackberries and placed in unbaked pie crust, dotted with butter and froze.  Will this turn out all right when I bake it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since the blueberries were already frozen, you are unlikely to have them making the crust soggy. It should work out well.

You will want to bake it from frozen, probably, rather than thawing.  You might want to slightly lower the oven temperature since it will need a little longer, and you don't want the crust to over brown.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this without any big issues.

If you aren't starting with frozen fruit take your pie pan, line with foil add your fruit mixture and freeze separately, once frozen remove and assemble your pie in the frozen state.

Makes it easy to bake a pie on short notice or when items aren't in season.